# Convert Objective-C method to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using a custom `UISwitch` Control called [DVSwitch](https://github.com/Voley/DVSwitch) which is written in Objective-C for a Swift/ Xcode6 project. I need to call its `-setPressedHandler:` Method and having a hard time converting it to Swift. Can anyone please show me how to write the code block below in Swift.

```
[switcher setPressedHandler: ^(NSUInteger index) {
    NSLog(@"Did switch to index: %lu", (unsigned long)index);
}];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax of Block in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038713/syntax-of-block-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be:

```
switcher.setPressedHandler() { index in
    println("Did switch to index: \(index)")
}
```

Obviously, you must include the appropriate DVSwitch header in the project's bridging header.